# Angular 6 checkbox filter overrides previous checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, angular, filter

I am trying to build a filter using checkboxes. Down below is a snippet of my code:

filter.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter2'
})
@Injectable()
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], field: string, value: string): any[] {
    if (!items) {
      return [];
    }
    if (!field || !value) {
      return items;
    }

    var newArray = [];
    items.filter(singleItem => {
      if (singleItem != null && singleItem[field] != null && singleItem[field] != undefined && singleItem[field].includes(value)) {
        newArray.push(singleItem);
      }
    })
    return newArray;
  }
}
```

app.html

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let group of groups;  let i=index">
     <label class="btn btn-filter" id="bttns">
            <input type="checkbox" name="customersGroupFilter" autoComplete="off" [value]="group" (change)="changeGroup($event)">
                      {{ group }}
     </label>&nbsp;
 </ng-container>

.....

 <tr *ngFor="let user of usersList | filter2: 'group' : groupValue">

.....
```

app.ts

```
groups = ['a', 'b', c']
usersList = [{'name': 'john', 'group': 'a'}, {'name': 'mike', 'group': 'a'}, {'name': 'doe', 'group': 'b'}, {'name': 'tim', 'group': 'c'}]
groupValue

changeGroup(event) {
    this.groupValue = event.target.value
}
```

This works fine, but if I want to make multiple checks, the new checkbox value will always override my previous value, so multicheck won't be possible.

eg.:

> if I check group 'a' => it will return me john, mike
>
> if I check 'a' and 'b' => it will return me only doe

How can I modify my code to achieve what I want? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example if you really want to use Angular Pipe
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qw7kkf

1. You need to change your transform function in Pipe to support multiple group values

   ```
   transform(items: any[], field: string, value: string[]): any[] {
   if (!items) {
     return [];
   }
   if (!field || !value || value.length <= 0) {
     return items;
   }
   return items.filter(singleItem => {
     return (singleItem != null && singleItem[field] != null && singleItem[field] != undefined && value.indexOf(singleItem[field]) >= 0);
   });
   ```

   }

See that the type of *value* changed from **string** to **string[]**, and also the usage of *Array.filter* function

2.Change the type of *groupValue* from **string** to **string[]**, too. And this is your new **changeGroup()** function

```
changeGroup(event) {
  const group = event.target.value;
  const index = this.groupValue.indexOf(group);
  if ( index < 0) {
    this.groupValue.push(group);
  } else {
    this.groupValue.splice(index, 1);  
  }
  const newGroupValue = [];
  newGroupValue.push.apply(newGroupValue, this.groupValue);
  this.groupValue = newGroupValue;
}
```

Now to check a group also means trigger it in *groupValue*. And notice that how cumbersome I have to assign a new array to *this.groupValue* every time, because if you don't do so, the *filter2* Pipe won't detect the change "**inside**" *this.groupValue* array.
That's also the reason I don't recommend Pipe for your usage scenario, it's a bit over for Angular Pipe.

Comment: I must not have pipes, it's just a version of how I thought I can handle the situation; any other solution is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You are doing some things the wrong way. First, [you shouldn't use a filtering pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe). That filter will get called many times per second and will potentially slow down your application. Instead, run the  filter function on click of a checkbox.

```
changeGroup(event) {
    // filter function here
}
```

The second thing that jumps to my eyes is the misuse of filter. `Array.filter()` filters the array for you - the if statement must really be the callback's return value

```
this.newArray =  items.filter(singleItem => 
  singleItem != null && singleItem[field] != null && singleItem[field] != undefined && singleItem[field].includes(value)
)
```

You can then use newArray...

So your formerly filtered userList becomes

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of newArray">
```

Comment: So in my `changeGroup(event)` which function should I call, because I didn't understand very well what you are saying, sorry.

Comment: Basically, you can call the corrected `transform` method in changeGroup and apply it's result on newArray in your component. The answer you marked as correct is not the way you should do that!!! @Tenzolinho

Comment: The problem is that my pipe does not support multiple values; as you say, it's still not working.